# Android custom serialization access to context

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-context

I have an object with a BitmapDrawable field that I would like to serialize.
I've implemented custom serialization/deserialization with the following methods:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    art.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, out);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    art = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
}
```

This works, except that the BitmapDrawable constructor without resources is deprecated, and I'd like to use the preferred constructor. What is a good way to get an Android context passed down into readObject?

Comment: Does your object class use a `Context` for anything else? Do you pass it one in its constructor?

Comment: No, but if I did pass it one just for this, because I need it in the readObject method, I assume I wouldn't want to be serializing contexts, so in readObject I wouldn't have access to it, right?

Comment: Right, right. You can't serialize `Context`s, even if you wanted to. You may have to alter your class to hold just the `Bitmap`, and create a `BitmapDrawable` as needed. Otherwise, you might just be stuck with the deprecated constructor.

Comment: Well, the problem with using the deprecated constructor is that by not having the resources means that the density gets set incorrectly

Comment: Yeah, I'd've gone with my first suggestion, anyway. Seems cleaner. Then you could just implement a factory method that takes a `Context` and returns a `BitmapDrawable`.

Comment: That seems reasonable, and did the trick. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Going to quote Mike M's answer from the comments above so that this question can be closed.

> You may have to alter your class to hold just the Bitmap, and create a BitmapDrawable as needed.

Basically instead of turning the Bitmap into a BitmapDrawable in the class, I do it in the activities where I need a Drawable (because I have access to a context in those locations). So instead of serializing a BitmapDrawable I am serializing a Bitmap, which does not require a context to deserialize.